# Assigning Time of Project Compile to Jar to a String / Double?

Tags: java

I am working on making a project with a group of friends and we are each contributing to the project. It's a server run from a jar file launched with a batch script. The server needs to load / launch (bringing it online) and we use System.out.println() to print to the command line each part of the project's launch as different sections are printed.

I was wondering if it is possible to create a double or a string that holds the value of the time the server was last compiled on so we can know the date of the jar the current online server runs on.

For example: if I compile on 091520182031 (mm/dd/yyyy/24-hour time), I would want that value of 091520182031 to be assigned to some double or string, we'll call it (string / double time) and I run launch the server 2 days later, I want to use System.out.println(time) so I can see on launch.

I hope this make sense. I couldn't really find anything of this. Would be neat so we dont have to manually change it every time

Comment: 1.) Why a double? 2.) You should probably set a property in the manifest. This can easily be done with a build tool like Gradle or Maven, your IDE may also support it.

Comment: Sure. But the solution depends on what you're using to build, and you didn't say.